# Bash Shell awk/xargs magic

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I'm trying to learn a little awk foo. I have a CSV where each line is of the format partial_file_name,file_path. My goal is to find the files (based on partial name) and move them to their respective new paths. I wanted to combine the forces of find,awk and mv to achieve this but I'm stuck implementing. I wanted to use awk to separate the terms from the csv file so that I could do something like 
`find . -name '*$1*' -print | xargs mv {} $2{}`
where $1 and $2 are the split terms from the csv file. Anyone have any ideas?
 -peace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've got things mixed up here. `{}` can only be used in find, and only once. I.e you cannot do something like `find -name '*.jpg' -exec mv {} {}.png`.

Do this:

```
$ cat korv
foo.txt,/hello/
bar.jpg,/mullo/
$ awk -F, '{print $1 " " $2}' korv
foo.txt /hello/
bar.jpg /mullo/
```

-F sets the delimiter, so the above will split using ",". Next, add * to the filenames:

```
$ awk -F, '{print "*"$1"*" " " $2}' korv
*foo.txt* /hello/
*bar.jpg* /mullo/
**
```

This shows I have an empty line. We don't want this match, so we add a rule:

```
$ awk -F, '/[a-z]/{print "*"$1"*" " " $2}' korv
*foo.txt* /hello/
*bar.jpg* /mullo/
```

Looks good, so encapsulate all this to mv using a subshell:

```
$ mv $(awk -F, '/[a-z]/{print "*"$1"*" " " $2}' korv)
$
```

Done.

Comment: yes i was a bit mixed up there. Cool sol'n and nice explanation. Many thanks

Comment: No, xargs -i certainly supports {} as well, but it accepts a single argument at a time.

Comment: `echo foo | xargs -n 1 echo mv {} {}.txt` => "mv {} {}.txt foo" for me.

Comment: You forgot the `-i` from `xargs -i`.

Comment: Also, running it in backticks will copy all files to the final destination directory.

Comment: Just to spell out tripleee's suggestion (I assume you meant capital -I): `echo foo | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo mv {} {}.txt` => mv foo foo.txt

Comment: you can use `{}` more than once, eg. `find . -name file -exec mv {} {}.txt \;` is valid.

Comment: @MiloWielondek Yes @ bos is misunderstanding the command syntax and using his authority to remove edits on his answer to remove the wrong statement, trying to be both executive and judge, without even doing due diligence by verifying his claims.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need awk for this.  There isn't really anything here which awk does better than the shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=,
while read file target; do
  find . -name "$file" -print0 | xargs -ir0 mv {} "$target"
done <path_to_csv_file
```

If you have special characters in the file names, you may need to tweak the `read`.

Answer (score 0):

what about using awk's system command:

```
awk '{ system("find . -name " $1 " -print | xargs -I {} mv {} " $2 "{}"); }'
```

example arguments in the csv file: test.txt ./subdirectory/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't know about that command. So would the full call look like:
`awk '{ system("find . -name " $1 " -print | xargs -I {} mv {} " $2 "{}"); }' path_to_csv_file`?

Comment: What's the last '"{}"' for?  At least for me, it works better if you take that out.

Comment: @adbo: Run it with -F, for a csv file. Bos's solution is way better, assuming that you only want to copy files in the current directory (in which case find becomes completely unnecessary).

Comment: @tripleee: Though it still works with the last {}, you're right in that it's not necessary. mv file.txt ./subdir/file.txt works the same as mv file.txt ./subdir/. In retrospect, I would take it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*err" -size "+10c" | awk -F.err '{print $1".job"}' | xargs -I {} qsub {}
```